# Process-specific instances of non-custom PerformanceCounters throw System.InvalidOperationException upon initialization

Tags: c#, .net, performancecounter

I've been banging my head against the wall all day trying to solve this issue...

Let's say I execute the following block of code inside a console application that starts up *and runs this block of code within seconds of launching*:

```
var p = new PerformanceCounter(".NET CLR Jit", "# of Methods Jitted","Process Name", true);
long raw = p.RawValue; //throws
```

I get the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The Counter layout for the Category specified is invalid, a counter of the type:  AverageCount64, AverageTimer32, CounterMultiTimer, CounterMultiTimerInverse, CounterMultiTimer100Ns, CounterMultiTimer100NsInverse, RawFraction, or SampleFraction has to be immediately followed by any of the base counter types: AverageBase, CounterMultiBase, RawBase or SampleBase.
[01:23:02][Step 1/1]    at System.Diagnostics.CategorySample.GetCounterDefinitionSample(String counter)
[01:23:02][Step 1/1]    at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.NextSample()
[01:23:02][Step 1/1]    at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.NextValue()
```

These are built-in CLR counters, and I've verified that they are correctly installed on the target machine.

Here's what is really weird: if I have Performance Monitor out and I refresh my list of available counter instances as the process launches, everything works fine and every subsequent run of my console app runs without issue. If I don't manually do that, I continuously get this error.

I'm running this console app on a build server that spawns fresh VMs from saved images on Azure, so I ultimately need to come up with some sort of programmatic way of making this work. I could also try modifying the machine image if this is fundamentally a permissions issue or something else like that, but I don't think it is.

I've eliminated the following possible sources of PerformanceCounter errors already:

1. [I scan to find the correct, unique name of the process if there are multiple instances running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115436/performance-counter-by-process-id-instead-of-name)
2. [My console app runs with AnyCpu, with prefer 32-bit disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572397/reading-performance-counter-from-c-instance-does-not-exist-in-the-specified-ca)
3. [I have run lodctr and do not have a corrupt performance counter registry AFAIK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286527/how-can-i-get-performance-counter-to-work-without-getting-the-user-to-rebuild-wi)
4. [I destroy and recreate my counters upon exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171865/performance-counter-system-invalidoperationexception-category-does-not-exist/8265208#8265208)
5. And I cache my counter instances if they don't throw.
6. I actually try running my application multiple times in a row to see if the process-specific instances get created after the app exits the first time.
7. I exponentially back-off and wait a few seconds each time a counter fails to be recreated, in case the system needs more time to initialize them.

So I'm at a loss to explain how to fix this issue - any ideas on what the real underlying problem is?

Comment: This is an environmental problem, the code that fails iterates the counters for a category and it encountered a bad counter definition.  It is not implausible that Perfmon repairs the problem.  This data comes from the registry so that points the finger at one of those saved images.  Hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: @HansPassant yep, looks like you're right - pushed some debug code to iterate over the `PerformanceCounterCategory` and saw this come back: ------------ STARTING NBench.PerformanceCounters.Tests.Performance.ProcessJitSpec+TimeInJit ---------- 
[05:52:42][Step 1/1] ---- DEBUG -----
[05:52:42][Step 1/1] Multi-instance? SingleInstance
[05:52:42][Step 1/1] ERROR: Error while executing the tests.

Comment: It's reporting the entire ".NET CLR Jit" category as single instance, which is obviously wrong